# Installing numpy+MKL on Linux to use cvxopt package

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, intel-mkl, cvxopt

In Windows, I have a Python 3.6 script that uses the `cvxopt` package which needs numpy + MKL for it to work. numpy + MKL was successfully installed using [the prebuilt binaries here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy).

**Problem:** Now the script also needs to be run in Ubuntu 16.04, but `pip install numpy` installs the version of numpy without MKL.

How can I install numpy+MKL on a Linux system to be able to use the `cvxopt` package?

Comment: You can build it from source with linked to MKL

Comment: Easy solution: use anaconda's python-distribution. (although you did not make clear why you want MKL; cvxopt will work fine with alternatives)

Comment: @sascha I created my virtualenv using `conda create --name myEnv python=3.6`, maybe this is why it doesnt include numpy+MKL?

Comment: @sascha What alternatives are there in order to use `cvxopt`?

Comment: It does not matter if your numpy is using / linked against MKL, OpenBlas, Atlas (and even on default Ubuntu this should work already when just using pip install numpy)... Your conda call should be MKL-based. Don't expect it to have a name including MKL. It's the default by now. Look here at SO for reading out numpy's setup.